# List index out of range and loops aren't iterating

Tags: python

It's probably easier if I explain by showing you the .csv file I'm trying to manipulate:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4kms4hm28y7sv8w/Test1.csv

I have many hundreds of lines of data such as this, but we've decided we want it in a different format, with each of the fossil genus and species (columns W, X, Y) in rows of their own.

I have very limited Python knowledge, but I wanted to try and use it regardless to split these cells and insert each value into the row below from which it was split. I was going to manually then drag them across to the correct column and drag down the other details on Excel.

The code:

```
#nektonic=[row[22].split(',') for row in data]
#infaunal=[row[23].split(',') for row in data]  
#epifaunal=[row[24].split(',') for row in data] 

f=0
r=0

def splitfossils(f, r): 
    #f=0 #fossil index: counter that moves the selection along the fossils in a cell that are being split by commas
    for row in data:
        r=(data.index(row)+1) #row index: counter so that split fossils can be inserted beneath the row that is being processed; the +1 is to ensure that the counter starts on 1, not 0.
        if row[22] == '':
            continue #if no fossils are found, move onto the next row
        else:
            nektonic=[row[22].split(',')] #nektonic fossils are found to be in the 23rd column of the spreadsheet
            if len(nektonic) == 1:
                data.insert(r,(nektonic[f])) #if only one fossil is present in the nektonic list, insert only that fossil and do not increase counter number 
            else:
                while f < len(nektonic): #the while loop will loop until the split fossils have been processed
                    data.insert(r,(nektonic[f])) #each split fossil will be inserted into a row below                                   
                    f=f+1 #the fossil index moves on to the next fossil
                    r=r+1 #the next fossil will be inserted into the row below the previous fossil
                    return f
                    return r


splitfossils(f, r)
```

The current error message is that the list index is out of range (highlighting row 19 and 34).

I tried playing around for a while by passing various variables through the function to see if that made a difference, but the previous error I had was that the "for" loop would not iterate. The length of the "data" list was 29, but the only print I would print out nektonic[f] would be "Stomohamites Simplex", the only value from 1W in the spreadsheet.

I'm not really sure if all these loops within loops would work, like I said my knowledge is very basic. Could anyone tell me what's wrong with the code and what might've been an easier way to sort out this problem?

Thanks

Edit: I completed changed my approach to what I have done this instead. It now works, thank you very much for all of your help.

```
import csv

out=open("Test1.csv", "rb")
data=csv.reader(out)
data=[row for row in data]
out.close() 

nektonic=[]

def splitfossils(): 
    for row in data:        
        nektonic=row[22].split(',')
        if len(nektonic)>1:
            for fossil in nektonic:
                newrow=[0 for i in range(22)]
                newrow.append(fossil)
                output.writerow(newrow)

        else:
            output.writerow(row)
    return data

out=open("new_test2.csv", "wb")
output=csv.writer(out)
splitfossils()
```

Comment: The '22' seems a little worrisome.  Is there any way you can identify that column without a hard number?  At the least, you should check the size of the row before accessing '22' and skip that row if its too small.

Comment: Three thoughts on your edited version: 1. What's the effect of `data=[row for row in data]`? As far as I can tell it just turns `data` into a list - but do you really need it? If so, you could just use `list(data)`. 2. It would be a good idea to not have `splitfossils` act on global variables but rather pass it all the stuff it needs, i.e. the it could take an input list of rows and produces an output list of rows. 3. Instead of `[0 for i in range(22)]` you can say `[0] * 22`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, identation matters. Hence, the code

```
while f < len(nektonic): #the while loop will loop until the split fossils have been processed
    data.insert(r,(nektonic[f])) #each split fossil will be inserted into a row below                                   
    f=f+1 #the fossil index moves on to the next fossil
    r=r+1 #the next fossil will be inserted into the row below the previous fossil
    return f
    return r
```

returns after a single iteration, because the `return f` is hit right away. You probably meant to indent that a bit further left (both of the `returns` actually).

That being said, in Python you don't need to use indices to iterate an array, you would just do:

```
for fossil in nektonic:
    data.insert(r, fossil)
```

Same for the outer loop which iterates the rows.

Comment: Only one of the `return` statements will ever be executed, so it would have to be `return f,r` anyway.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Right, when I wrote `both of the returns actually` I meant to imply that the second return is indented even less than the first one - but maybe the OP wanted a tuple indeed. In any case, we all agree that two subsequent return statements (in the same scope!) don't make too much sense. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to modify the list you are iterating. I don't think this is a good approach in Python. Try to copy your data to the new list (it is memory efficient as the objects are referenced rather than copied). Something like this:

```
import csv

out=open("Test1.csv", "rb")
data=csv.reader(out)
data=[row for row in data]
out.close()    

#nektonic=[row[22].split(',') for row in data]
#infaunal=[row[23].split(',') for row in data] 
#epifaunal=[row[24].split(',') for row in data]

def splitfossils():
    result = []
    for row in data:
        if row[22] == '':
            continue #if no fossils are found, move onto the next row
        else:
            nektonic=[row[22].split(',')]
            result.append(row)
            result.append(nektonic)
    return result


print splitfossils()
```

I am not sure if the above code is the direct answer to your problem, but try it in this way...